# Chat head bubbles like Facebook Messenger without permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am working on floating widgets like Facebook Messenger, but this feature requires a permission to draw view on top of the other apps (SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW).

We know that Android introduced run-time permissions with Marshmallow. Consequently, if you install Facebook Messenger and activate head bubbles, Android have to ask this permission. However, Android doesn't ask any permission request for Facebook Messenger or Fabulous.

I tried [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-chat-head/), and Android requests permission in this tutorial. Why Android doesn't request this permission in Facebook Messenger or Fabulous?

Comment: The only reason could be that they are using `targetSdkVersion` set to 22 or lower

Answer (score 2):

> SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

is not normal permission like other permissions that has a normal popup, the permission is called 
**Draw overlay permission** 
if you downloaded the Application from play store  by default this permission is enabled 
you can check from that by going to

> Settings - > Apps -> Advanced permission from above or inside the app info   ->  Draw over other apps it will be enabled by default for apps installed from Play store.